# In Artifactory, is there a way to be notified when property was added/changed?

Tags: artifactory

I'm using artifactory pro. I upload builds from jenkins with the "Generic-Artifactory Integration"

I've created a property set that users can attach to builds and as an admin, I want to be notified when someone add or change a property.

I'm already using the 'Watch' option - but that only notify when the artifact itself was moved/deleted/created/copied

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by implementing a custom [User Plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins).

Specifically, you would want to implement `beforePropertyCreate` and/or `beforePropertyDelete`.

You can find a quick example of a "protect property edit" [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/security/protectPropertiesEdit.groovy)